# no [query] registered for [query] error int ltr plugin of elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using [ltr](https://github.com/o19s/elasticsearch-learning-to-rank) plugin for elasticsearch and I am doing exactly what documentation said. here is my featureset:

```
{
   "validation": {
     "params": {
         "keywords": "rambo"
     },
     "index": "movies"
    },
    "featureset": {
        "name": "movie_features",
        "features": [
            {
                "name": "title_query",
                "params": [
                    "keywords"
                ],
                "template_language": "mustache",
                "template": {
                    "query": {
                        "match": {
                            "title": "{{keywords}}"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

when I submit this request, I get the following error:

> ```
> {
>     "error": {
>         "root_cause": [
>             {
>                 "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
>                 "reason": "Cannot store element, validation failed."
>             }
>         ],
>         "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
>         "reason": "Cannot store element, validation failed.",
>         "caused_by": {
>             "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
>             "reason": "all shards failed",
>             "phase": "query",
>             "grouped": true,
>             "failed_shards": [
>                 {
>                     "shard": 0,
>                     "index": "movies",
>                     "node": "OixZfLQjRzmcY8yDxTCt9w",
>                     "reason": {
>                         "type": "query_shard_exception",
>                         "reason": "Cannot create query while parsing feature [title_query]",
>                         "index_uuid": "9TSirwWkQNOuMAkHFMpGvw",
>                         "index": "movies",
>                         "caused_by": {
>                             "type": "parsing_exception",
>                             "reason": "no [query] registered for [query]",
>                             "line": 1,
>                             "col": 10
>                         }
>                     }
>                 }
>             ]
>         }
>     },
>     "status": 400
> }
> ```

so what is wrong? it seems elasticsearch can not build the query, but I don't know what should I change in my query.

Comment: I also have the same error. I can not add function_score in features array of LTR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. you should remove query keyword in template:

```
"template": {
    "match": {
        "title": "{{keywords}}"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check here is that the feature you are referencing should be indexed, i.e. it should not have `index: false` set in the index mapping.

If the field is not indexed but `doc_values` is enabled (or not disabled) then that should also work, but there will be a performance penalty. As such it is best if all referenced fields are indexed (which is the default behaviour).